# flex different behaviour between browser

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

My flexbox combination are working erratic between browsers.

I can not comprehend why a child with position absolute of a flexbox parent, can not place the element child just right in the middle. For now the expected result can be achieve in chrome, but Firefox and Safari show a totally different result.

I've been reading this articles to understand why I do not get the result I want on these browsers.

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid purple;
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.main   a {
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
}
.container-flex {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #444;

}

.item-center-absolute {
  position: absolute;
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
  border-right: 8px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid tomato;
  bottom: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <a href="#">Something</a>
    <div class="container-flex">
      <div class="item-center-absolute"></div>
      <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The result at codepen is different:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oGbaGe

```
.main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid purple;
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;

  a {
    display: block;
    padding: 1em;
  }
}

.container-flex {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #444;

}

.item-center-absolute {
  position: absolute;
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
  border-right: 8px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid tomato;
  bottom: -10px;
}
```

Comment: Due to a change it the specs. there is an inconsistent behavior cross browsers. The duplicate link show how to solve it

Comment: appreciate @LGSon I was looking this answer before make a new question but I didn't found it. Thanks for the link.